# Delete currently loaded assembly

Tags: c#, file-io, filehandle

In my application comes with an uninstaller.
Everything is working fine, except that I can't find no way to delete the uninstaller.exe file when it's all done.

I tried to copy the current assembly exe into a temp directory, but the file-handle of the original file is still locked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to PInvoke to do this. [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(VS.85).aspx) has the ability to schedule deleting the file on next reboot.

> If dwFlags specifies MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and lpNewFileName is NULL, MoveFileEx registers the lpExistingFileName file to be deleted when the system restarts.

Something like:

```
[return: MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport ("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveFileEx (string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

public static bool ScheduleDelete (string fileFullName) {
    if (!File.Exists (fileFullName))
        throw new InvalidOperationException ("File does not exist.");

    return MoveFileEx (fileFullName, null, 0x04); //MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x04
}
```

Comment: Thanks! works great... never would've think of this by myself 
but is there's anyway of deleting it right away? I know there are uninstallers which does exactly that!

Comment: Perhaps the uninstaller which does that are executed by some other engine rather than being the engine itself. For example, if you have a msi, it is executed by windows installer, which in effect a different application, so it can delete the msi. But in your case, it is the engine itself. Deleting a locked file (any file, not just exe) will perhaps be file system stuff...

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting if you posted some code of how you exactly copy the uninstaller.exe and change execution to that specific executable.
I think [unloading the application domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9(VS.80).aspx) will free the file-handle.

Comment: nothing fancy, simply copy the file to a temp directory (using File.Copy)
starting it using Prcess.Start and disposing the original

What might help me is a way of starting an exe without the Process class (more to the PInvoke direction)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you want by using [shadow copying of assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx), but I haven't tried that for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "cmd" with delay:

```
    internal static void ExitAndDelete()
    {
        var f = Application.ExecutablePath;
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C timeout 2&del \"" + f + "\"") { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
    }
```