# Cmd and C# delete file

Tags: c#, cmd, delete-file

I'm trying to make an updater in C# and I want to delete the updater once it's done.
So I have this code in C#:

```
var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe";
Process.Start("cmd.exe /c del " + path);
```

But I get this error message:

> Win32Exception was unhandled
>   The system cannot find the file specified

But I'm sure the path is spelled right, so I don't think that's the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the File.Delete() static method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

Comment: Try printing out path.  I think you'll be surprised at what you see.

Comment: As an aside, you should consider using `System.IO.Path.Combine` to build path strings instead of using straight string concats.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068846/delete-currently-loaded-assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c del \"{0}\"", path);
process.Start();
```

Or

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", string.Format("/c del \"{0}", path));
```

Comment: how about deleting a folder that is shared that would prompt to confirm the deletion? how to avoid that prompt message and delete it directly?

Comment: @Juran sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here: [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Aditional solution is to build a BAT file and inside it to call del.